# VB: Is it possible to attach a number (index) to a form object name?

Tags: arrays, object

I have 10 textboxes on my form with names: textbox**1**, textbox**2**, ..., textbox**10**

Is it possible to assign the 'number' of the form object textbox(**1,2,..10**) by doing iteration?

This is my current situation, can anybody pls fix the way to give number to the **[???]** below? If possible without the if statement. Thanks so much before!

```
    Dim arr(0 To 9) As String
    For index = 1 To arr.Length + 1
        arr.SetValue(Me.TextBox[???].Text(), index)
    Next
```

[???] should be the same as the index number

Comment: VB does not use square brackets for much of anything except non-standard identifiers. Can you clarify the syntax there?

Comment: I know VB does not use square brackets .. I just used square brackets to describe the situation where I wanted to assign numbers next to my textboxes: textbox1, textbox2, textbox3, textbox4, textbox5, textbox6, textbox7, textbox8, textbox9, textbox10. I want to assign the numbers 1 to 10 in a "loop..through" process without typing them explicitly (in a way variable works). I hope I have made myself understood.